# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: azure, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, binary, debian

I am trying to run my application on Debian server. I installed chrome version Google Chrome 121.0.6167.139 to debian. When ı run application on Azure Devops, ı took this error
"Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"

My driver manager code is:

```
 public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driverPool.get() == null) {
            /*
            We read our browserType from configuration.properties.
            This way, we can control which browser is opened from outside
            our code, from configuration.properties.
             */
            String browserType = ConfigurationReader.getProperty("browser");
            /*
            Depending on the browserType that will be return from configuration.properties file
            switch statement will determine the case, and open the matching browser
             */



            switch (browserType) {
                case "chrome":
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("incognito");
                    driverPool.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
                    driverPool.get().manage().window().maximize();
                    driverPool.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
                    break;
                case "firefox":
                    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("incognito");
                    driverPool.set(new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions));
                    driverPool.get().manage().window().maximize();
                    driverPool.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
                case "headless-chrome":
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("incognito");
                    chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
                    driverPool.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
                    driverPool.get().manage().window().maximize();
                    driverPool.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return driverPool.get();
    }


[ERROR] Security Transactions Security Transfer İşlemi #3.Security Transactions Customer Transactions Out Input İşlemi  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary 
Host info: host: 'debian', ip: '127.0.1.1'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.0-22-amd64', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [incognito, --remote-allow-origins=*, incognito], extensions: []}}]}]
```

Could you please help me on what is wrong?

My dependies are like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using Selenıum Web driver version 4.12.2 as UI testing tool and Java 11 as a programming language. I am using bonigarcia 5.4.1 as webdrivernanager. What should ı do to launch Chrome browser on Debian server. Should ı install any library?

Comment: show your driver initialization code.  You shouldn't need webdrivermanager dependency, btw... that's built-in to Selenium now.

Comment: Remove: WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); and the webdrivermanager dependency, and check again.  It should run the built-in webdrivermanager.